# pointer to pointer, I am lost

Tags: c

This is my code, it compile and runs:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{ 
    int i,j; 
    int** p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));

    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); 
    p[1] = p[0];

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
            {
                p[i][j] = i + j; 
            }
    } 

    printf("p[0][0] = %d",p[0][0]); 

    return 0; 
}
```

When this program is run, I got: P[0][0] = 1. Why not P[0][0] = 0?

Comment: the issue is here `p[1] = p[0];`

Comment: @Ôrel why? please explain

Comment: [Never cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/4228131)

Answer (score 7):

You are making `p[0]` and `p[1]` point to the same memory location. Later on, you run this loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
                    p[i][j] = i + j;
```

which sets `p[0][0]` to `0`. However, it is followed by setting `p[1][0]` to `1`. Since `p[0]` and `p[1]` are equal, `p[0][0]` ends up being `1` finally.

What you likely intended instead of

```
p[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); 
p[1] = p[0];
```

was a separate `malloc` for `p[1]` as well. Like this:

```
p[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); 
p[1] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: so based on your explanation, we need to allocate different memory for p[1]?
p[1] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));

Comment: @maku : Yes else they are just pointer and will point to same memory blocks.

Answer (score 4):

P[1] and p[0] are being assigned to the same memory location. So any change in p[1] changes p[0].You should allocate separate space for p[1] .

```
p[1]=malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Oh sorry. An old habit of mine. Thank you .